# Html(5) attributes for EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

I know this has been discussed a lot of times.

I'd like to use

```
@Html.EditorFor(u => u.Password, new { required = "required" })
```

Unfortunatley this isn't possible by default as the EditorFor overwrites the Html attributes.

I don't want to use TextBoxFor because I'd like the value to be formatted according to the DisplayFormat attribute.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by `overwrites the HTML attributes`?

Comment: @mosquito :What is your question actually? If you want required field validation you can set it in the model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write a custom editor template for the string type (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml`):

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
    ViewData
)
```

and then:

```
@Html.EditorFor(u => u.Password, new { required = "required" })
```

will work as expected.

Comment: So what did the OP mean by `overwrites the HTML attributes`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, why are you asking me? Ask the OP. I guess what he meant is that the `new { required = "required" }` parameter he was passing to the editor template had no effect whatsoever which is perfectly normal because the default editor template built-in ASP.NET MVC doesn't use them. That's why I suggested to create a custom editor template that will use those parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it's an option but you could just put [Required] as a property decorator on the Model.

Comment: No, this has no effects on the html attribute I want.